# Ubuntu 18.04 can't find any wi-fi connections

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 for almost 1 year on my Samsung Expert with Qualcomm QCA9377 adapter and it has been working fine. But since last week, no wireless connections are found. I have Windows also installed and all available connections appear normally so it is not a hardware issue.

I ran `lshw -C network` command and the following message regarding my wireless interface appears:

```
    *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 31
       serial: 98:83:89:8c:13:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-54-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:126 memory:ef000000-ef1fffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I also ran `lspci`, and I get the following message:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Another command I ran is `rfkill list all` and I got the message:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Apparently, the adapter is ok.

I also tried to update the whole system by doing the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Another thing I tried is iwconfig, and the following message appears:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

None of these helped. Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu? I have short experience in Ubuntu and Bash.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and post URL after running the wireless script and `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: I can't run the wireless script because when I run {wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&   chmod +x wireless-info &&   ./wireless-info} I get {wget: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0i' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1)
wget: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1)
}
I tried several times to install openssl but I can't.